# Getting a partial classname and defining a variable with regexp and jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

http://jsfiddle.net/cYmxB/

```
$('.change').click(function() {
    $('.link').each(function(e) {
        var color = this.className.match(/color-\w+/gi);
        alert(color);
    });
});​
```

I'd basically like this to alert the regular expression found with `\w+` rather than the entire string. How can I do this?

Additionally, how can I remove `color-` without removing the regular expression after this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the javascript regular expressions to loop though the matches which will return the groups in an array. You can also use the `replace` function with a group back reference to remove the color-

```
$('.change').click(function() {
    $('.link').each(function(e) {
        // find regex matching groups
        var regex = /color-(\w+)/gi;
        var match;
        while (match = regex.exec(this.className)) {
            alert(match[1]);
        }
        // remove color-
        this.className = this.className.replace(/color-(\w+)/gi, "$1");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cYmxB/2/

Answer (score 1):

Use a capturing group for the color:

```
$('.change').click(function() {
    $('.link').each(function(e) {
        var pattern = /color-(\w+)/gi;
        var match = pattern.exec(this.className);
        var color = match[1];
        alert(color);
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cYmxB/1/